# DotNetOpenAuth and ReturnToUrl in web forms

Tags: asp.net, dotnetopenauth

I'm using *asp.net* with *url rewrite*.

Inside *Page Load* I have the following code:

```
OpenIdLogin1.ReturnToUrl = @"~/Login"
```

When I log in and return to calling page, I get the following error message:

> Login failed: The openid.return_to parameter (http://localhost:12345/Login?dnoa.receiver=ctl00_phContent_ctl00_OpenIdLogin1&dnoa.UsePersistentCookie=Session&dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier=https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id) does not match the actual URL (http://localhost:12345/Templates/Pages/Login/Login.aspx?dnoa.receiver=ctl00_phContent_ctl00_OpenIdLogin1&dnoa.UsePersistentCookie=Session&dnoa.userSuppliedIdentifier=https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id&openid.ns=http://specs.openid.net/auth/2.0)

How can I change actual url to virtual url?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved the problem:

```
var openId = new OpenIdRelyingParty();
HttpContext httpContext = HttpContext.Current;

var headers = new WebHeaderCollection();
foreach (string header in httpContext.Request.Headers)
{
    headers.Add(header, httpContext.Request.Headers[header]);
}

string requestUrl = string.Format("http://localhost:12345/Login/{0}",
                                   httpContext.Request.Url.Query);

var requestInfo = new HttpRequestInfo(httpContext.Request.HttpMethod,
                                        new Uri(requestUrl),
                                        httpContext.Request.RawUrl, headers,
                                        httpContext.Request.InputStream);

var response = openId.GetResponse(requestInfo);
```

Comment: So I see that that is exactly what I gave in my answer as what you should do.  Why is it that you commented that it didn't work, and then posted your own answer that it did?

Answer (score 3):

In your call to `GetResponse`, pass in an `HttpRequestInfo` object that you initialize with the URL you want DotNetOpenAuth to see as the incoming URL.

Comment: I did that but it still returns me to the same url.